# Scala case class, modify a parameter in constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, apply, case-class

I have a case class

```
case class SiteID(channel: String, locale: String)
```

Locale can be "en-GB" or "en_GB" . So I want to replace  the hyphen by underscore.

The idea is to transform  , so there is this equality

> SiteID("blabla","en-GB") == SiteID("blabla","en_GB")

I tried with the following code

```
case class SiteID(channel: String, locale: String)

object SiteID{

  def apply(channel: String, locale: String):SiteID =  SiteID(channel,locale.replace("-","_") )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably calling recursively the apply method of the companion object.
Try using the new operator.

```
 object SiteID {
    def apply(channel: String, locale: String):SiteID =
       new SiteID(channel,locale.replace("-","_") )
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

With the Scala `case class` construct, the compiler automatically generates an `apply` method for you with the declared parameters. If you declare another one with the same parameter types as your case class, it takes precedence over the compiler's generated one.

So as stated in another answer your `apply` method is calling itself recursively; a solution was provided. If you additionally need to ensure that no `SiteID("bla","en-GB")` value will get instantiated, you should declare the constructor of your case class as private:

```
case class SiteID private(channel: String, locale: String)

object SiteID {
    def apply(channel: String, locale: String):SiteID =
        new SiteID(channel,locale.replace("-","_") )
}

SiteID("bla","en-GB") //SiteID(a,en_GB)
new SiteID("bla","en-GB") //error
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that's rather close to what you want (you can make the `Point`'s constructor `protected`):

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)
class PolarPoint(r: Double, alpha: Double) extends Point(r*Math.cos(alpha), r*Math.sin(alpha))
```

and

```
@main def main(): Unit = {
  println(Point(10,10))
  println(PolarPoint(10, Math.PI/4))
}
```

prints:

```
Point(10.0,10.0)
Point(7.0710678118654755,7.071067811865475)
```

and `r` and `alpha` do not become members of PolarPoint:

```
public class PolarPoint extends Point {
    public PolarPoint(final double r, final double alpha) {
        super(r * Math.cos(alpha), r * Math.sin(alpha));
    }
}
```

If it's ok to reference objects as `Foo`s but create `FooImpl`s. you can do something like:

```
case class Foo protected(x:Int)
class FooImpl(x0:Int) extends Foo(myFunc(x0))
```